# PHP - if variable

Tags: php, syntax

Sorry I'm still really new to PHP but I was wondering if someone can give me a hand to get this to work? I'm a little confused

Something like

```
$name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']);
$var2 = bad
if $name = $var2 redirect to error.html
else continue script
```

But I don't know the proper syntax. sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: you shouldn't ask for such syntax stuff. If you have any problem understanding something then post here. I will downvote it! and also give it a flag. So delete this post or modify so that it reflects the community's rules.

Comment: Why downvote it? I am literally asking for code help on a forum dedicated to helping people with codes. What is your problem? If you have an issue with my post then don't comment, leave. You're not welcome to post on my questions if you're only full of hate and negativity.

Comment: look, I didn't even downvote. To others, it was like inappropriate so they downvoted it. You should learn how to write, use basic functions in a language. Here we don't ask someone to write code for us, do we? And you are a new member of this wonderful community. So welcome.

Comment: I am not asking for you to write my code for me as I know most of the basic stuff anyway. I am asking for assistance, which is what this community is based around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your PHP code as below,

```
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']);
$var2 = "bad";

if($name == $var2) {
    header("Location: error.html");
}

// here onwards you can do whatever you want to do
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please, be aware that `header('Location: ...')` does not stop the script. You have to add a `exit(0);` after.